# Unable to use Plotly on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, jupyter

I have written a piece of code to generate a plot using Plotly in JupyterLab. The code is running just fine but I'm unable to view the graph

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = [
    go.Candlestick(
        x = Data365.index,
        low = Data365['Low'],
        high = Data365['High'],
        open = Data365['Open'],
        close = Data365['Close'],
        increasing_line_color = 'green',
        decreasing_line_color = 'red'
    )
]

figure.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False,title = 'Daily OHLC for the last 1 Year', yaxis_title = 'Price in USD', xaxis_title = 'Date') 

figure.show()
```

Plotly Version: 4.10.0

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading `plotly` might be your best bet here.

With `plotly==5.6.0` the [candlestick chart example](https://plotly.com/python/candlestick-charts/) from the plotly documentation worked in JupyterLab.

Code:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv")

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Candlestick(
            x=df["Date"],
            open=df["AAPL.Open"],
            high=df["AAPL.High"],
            low=df["AAPL.Low"],
            close=df["AAPL.Close"],
        )
    ]
)

fig
```

JupyterLab output:

[image: Screenshot from JupyterLab, the top shows the Python code and the bottom half shows a candlestick plot produced by running the code]